# Project Euler #1-3 in VBA

Tags: programming-challenge, vba

Self explanatory, and all the functions contain descriptions of their specific problem statements.

Since this is project Euler, I would be particularly interested in any analysis of the functions' computational efficiency.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ProjectEuler1() As Long

    '/ Problem statement: sum all multiples of 3 and 5 from 1 to 999

    Dim total As Long
    Dim i As Long

        For i = 1 To 999

            If i Mod 3 = 0 Or i Mod 5 = 0 Then

                total = total + i

            End If

        Next i

    ProjectEuler1 = total

End Function

Public Function ProjectEuler2() As Long

    '/ Problem statement: sum all even Fibonacci numbers below 4 Million

    Dim fiboA As Long, fiboB As Long, currentFibo As Long '/ alternating fibonacci numbers
    Dim bIsHigher As Boolean

        fiboA = 1
        fiboB = 1
        currentFibo = 2

    Dim total As Long

        Do While currentFibo < 4000000

            If currentFibo Mod 2 = 0 Then total = total + currentFibo

            If bIsHigher Then
                    fiboA = currentFibo
                Else
                    fiboB = currentFibo
            End If

            bIsHigher = Not bIsHigher

            currentFibo = fiboA + fiboB

        Loop

    ProjectEuler2 = total

End Function

Public Function ProjectEuler3(ByVal numToFactorise As Long) As Long

    '/ Problem statement: find the largest prime factor of <big number>
    '/ I decided to generalise it

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sqrtLimit As Long
    Dim partiallyFactorisedNum As Long
    Dim largestPrimeDivisor As Long

        sqrtLimit = Application.Floor(numToFactorise ^ 0.5, 1)
        partiallyFactorisedNum = numToFactorise

        i = 2
        If partiallyFactorisedNum Mod i = 0 Then
            largestPrimeDivisor = i
            partiallyFactorisedNum = KeepDividingWhileInt(partiallyFactorisedNum, i)
        End If

        i = 3
        Do While i <= sqrtLimit

            If isPrime(i) Then

                If partiallyFactorisedNum Mod i = 0 Then
                    largestPrimeDivisor = i
                    partiallyFactorisedNum = KeepDividingWhileInt(partiallyFactorisedNum, i)
                End If

            End If

            i = i + 2
            sqrtLimit = Application.Floor(partiallyFactorisedNum ^ 0.5, 1)
        Loop

    If partiallyFactorisedNum > largestPrimeDivisor Then largestPrimeDivisor = partiallyFactorisedNum
    ProjectEuler3 = largestPrimeDivisor

End Function

Public Function isPrime(ByVal numTocheck As Long)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sqrtLimit As Long
        sqrtLimit = Application.Floor(numTocheck ^ 0.5, 1)

        isPrime = True

        If numTocheck Mod 2 = 0 And numTocheck <> 2 Then isPrime = False

        i = 3
        Do While i <= sqrtLimit And isPrime
            If numTocheck Mod i = 0 Then isPrime = False
            i = i + 2
        Loop

End Function

Public Function KeepDividingWhileInt(ByVal numToDivide As Long, ByVal divisor As Long) As Long

    Dim isDivisible As Boolean

        isDivisible = True
        Do While isDivisible
            If numToDivide Mod divisor = 0 Then
                    numToDivide = numToDivide / divisor
                Else
                    isDivisible = False
            End If
        Loop

    KeepDividingWhileInt = numToDivide

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While quickly running over your code, my eyes stopped on your function `KeepDividingWhileInt`.

It seemed over-complicated.

Let's write what it does:

1. Creates `isDivisible`
2. Sets `isDivisible` to `true`
3. Loops while `isDividible` is `true`:

   1. If `numToDivide Mod divisor` is `0`

      1. Divides `numToDivide` by `divisor`
   2. Else

      1. Sets `isDivisible` to `false`
4. Returns `numToDivide`

---

Well, there is a subtle bug on step 2: You assume that the number is divisible by `divisor`, which may not be true (e.g.: `KeepDividingWhileInt(3,2)`).

Also, the whole code could be extremely simplified, by moving the condition inside that `if` into the `while`.

Also, you could try to use `While ... Wend` instead of `Do While ... Loop`, as suggested by [@Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug). This point actually applies **everywhere** on your code.

---

The final result:

```vb
Public Function KeepDividingWhileInt(ByVal numToDivide As Long, ByVal divisor As Long) As Long

    While numToDivide Mod divisor = 0
        numToDivide = numToDivide / divisor
    Wend

    KeepDividingWhileInt = numToDivide

End Function
```

Oh my! The function is so simple that you can read it in a single sentence:

> Divide `numToDivide` by `divisor` while the reminder is `0`, returning the final result.

So simple, right?

Comment: Nice answer, except I don't know what `Do While...Loop`  is doing in the language - it's just one of the several *redundant-yet-different-because-why-not* ways of looping available in VBA. A simpler variant would be `While...Wend`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks a lot for that tip! Has been a few years since I've written any serous VB code. It is indeed simpler and to the point. It really looks a lot more natural. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Just a case of Do While ... Loop being what I initially encountered when learning the language.

Answer (score 4):

### Euler2

`bIsHigher` is a confusing variable name. It has the disadvantage of resembling Hungarian notation, so those exposed to that may read it as booleanIsHigher which makes no sense.

Rather than trying to find a better name, you can actually factor out the need for the variable. You get the same result from the following:

```
    Do While currentFibo < 4000000
        If currentFibo Mod 2 = 0 Then total = total + currentFibo
        fiboA = fiboB
        fiboB = currentFibo
        currentFibo = fiboA + fiboB
    Loop
```

which I would argue is closer to how the fibonacci sequence is actually derived as `fiboA` will always be (n-2) and `fiboB` will always be (n-1) instead of repeatedly trading places.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly the logic I was grasping at but couldn't quite articulate :)